# How to invoke a AWS Lambda function using SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm

I am new to AWS SSM, my requirement is I have a Lambda function created for which I have to invoke this lambda using an SSM Document is it achievable? If so how please explain.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly invoke Lambda from SSM. However, you can configure the SSM to write logs to AWS Cloudwatch. From Cloudwatch it is possible to invoke a Lambda function in response to logs.

Comment: Can a SSM Document have loops defined in it ?